# Webhooks provided by smart sheet api, is there any oauth auth workflow instead of HMAC Authentication?

Tags: smartsheet-api-2.0

Webhooks provided by smart sheet api, is there any oauth auth workflow instead of HMAC Authentication/authorization done

Answer (score 0):

There are detailed instructions here for how to implement OAuth 2.0: https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#third-party-app-development